# Mysql CASE: Multiple values in THEN

Tags: php, mysql, case

I have to pass multiple values in `THEN`.

Here is my code

```
select empid from emp_leave_authority where main_autority in
(
 CASE WHEN $emp_auth='577' THEN '541' END as column_1
 CASE WHEN $emp_auth='577' THEN '588' END as column_2                                                    
)
```

`$emp_auth` is ID in loop against which i am checking.

I am getting empty set of result.

My purpose is, If main_autority found is 577, replace it with 541 and 588. (Give those employee whose main_autority is 541 and 588).

Any ideas please

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're trying here.

Comment: Please explain you question properly.

Comment: If `$emp_auth` is being passed in from the PHP, then maybe you could just build the lists of IDs there, and generate the SQL dynamically, since they will need to be the same for all rows.

Comment: If found one ID then along with that consider other ID also. Simple sir

Comment: @hjpotter92 you got my point? Please ask if not

Comment: @AK47 Please see updted question now.

Comment: So,if I pass 577 only, then also I should get 2 records of 541,588. Correct?

Comment: @AK47 Yes. Now you get me.

Comment: Great!then I have given solution already, find it below.

Answer (score 0):

If I understodd it correctly, please try below code.

```
Create table #tmp
(
    searchvals int
)

If @myParam  = 577
Begin   
    insert into #tmp
    values (541)
    insert into #tmp
    values (588)
End
Else
Begin
    insert into #tmp
    values (@myParam)
End

select empid from emp_leave_authority where main_autority in (select searchvals from #tmp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do it in SQL. So, if `$emp_auth` is passed to procedure (Assuming) as parameter then you can do something like this

```
create procedure testproc(IN auth VARCHAR(5))   
as
begin
select empid from emp_leave_authority 
where main_autority in 
(
CASE auth
WHEN '577' THEN concat('541',',','588')  
END 
)                                                  
end
```

Comment: if i use comma separation in empid (like 541,588), it is not working.